# Using a Viewflipper with Gridview

Tags: android, viewflipper

I've created a calendar which works fine, using a GridView which has an OnClickListener.
Now I wrapped the two GridViews in a ViewFlipper. The ViewFlipper has an OnTouchListener which also works fine, I can change the view by using ontouch when dragging. The problem is though that I have to drag on the EMTPY space in the Activity in order to use the ViewFlipper. When I drag on the GridView, nothing happends at all. But I can click on the GridView for OnClickListener.

xml:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/weeks"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8">
    </GridView>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

android code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // Get the action that was done on this touch event
    switch (arg1.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
            downXValue = arg1.getX();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            // Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
            currentX = arg1.getX();    


            // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
            if (currentX - downXValue < -(arg0.getWidth()/3))
            {
                mdh.nextMonth();
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                currentMonth.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy").format(calendar.getTime()));
                cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateWeeks();
                 // Set the animation
                 vf.setInAnimation(arg0.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_in);
                  vf.setOutAnimation(arg0.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_out);
                  // Flip!
                  vf.showPrevious();
            }

            // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
            if (currentX - downXValue > arg0.getWidth()/3)
            {
                mdh.previousMonth();
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                currentMonth.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy").format(calendar.getTime()));
                cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateWeeks();
                 // Set the animation
                vf.setInAnimation(arg0.getContext(), R.anim.push_right_in);
                vf.setOutAnimation(arg0.getContext(), R.anim.push_right_out);
                  // Flip!
                 vf.showNext();
            }
            break;
        }
```

Comment: I think the behavior is the normal one as your listener is registered on the viewflipper. As it contains the gridviews, most of it is not "visibible", so not touchable. You might want to register both listeners on the gridviews and associate different gestures to them to trigger either the the flip or the other action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with a ViewFlipper and ScrollViews.
Try adding the onTouchListener to your GridView aswell and it should work.

Comment: Alright, I did indeed add ontouchlistener to my gridview, and now it works! Next question, would be: how can I move the screen with my finger, so I can see next screen before releasing the finger?

Comment: Check out this blogpost: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 2):

```
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```